# core.js:7187 ERROR Error: Error trying to diff ''. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Tags: angular8

I'm working with angular8, I have an `ngfor` that renders question templates, one of those is an autocomplete that when cleared (using the x chip) causes this error

> core.js:7187 ERROR Error: Error trying to diff ''. Only arrays and `iterables` are allowed core.Js:7187

I noticed that if I remove the `trackby` function from the `ngfor` the error would go, but I need the `trackby`

**EDIT**

inspecting the error on firefox i got this additional info:

```
ERROR Error: Error trying to diff ''. Only arrays and iterables are allowed
Angular 7
AutoComplete_ul_2_Template AutoComplete.js:246
Angular 68
RxJS 5
Angular 9
```

Comment: Can you please provide code indicating where exactly you are facing the issue?

Comment: the point is that the error is not indicating which file is causing it, it is refering some javascript file

Comment: that above error occurs when object is assigned to NgFor instead of Array

Comment: @HassanAbbass when cleared make sure that Ngfor assigned variable must be []

Comment: @VENKATESHCHAVVAKULA the problem is in the primeng autocomplete not in the ngFor, the ngfor variable is indeed an array (declared as empty array and gets fetched from a `datalist` ...